# Android Application which loads images from web services on a server

Tags: android, image, web-services, imagedownload

I am developing an android application which loads images from web and app running  only on 2G networks.Now what factors will you consider while developing it? any help on this question ?

Comment: Many people knows answer of that question but nobody will write any piece of code for you. You need to show us what have you tried, what did you do to develop your system etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only factor from users view is as I see: network, an this should you also have in mind while development. If your app can handle only meta-data i would prefer to download only metadata when phone will be on mobile network (mobile network is in most cases metered connection). When you will be on wifi you can also download images.

If your app need images immediately, then i suggest to resize/compress images on server side as much as possible to reduce data transfer. With that you will also speed up loading even if phone will be on non-metered connection.

Good experience will be then also if you can add settings for that. So user can decide if download images always or only when phone is on wifi.